# Show paypal buy button in fancybox popup?

Tags: popup, fancybox

How can I put this code into fancybox popup, and activate it whenever my `<a>` button gets pressed?

Here is the code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="IN">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item 1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Your info">Your info</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os0" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="More info">More info</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Any help or suggestions are well appreciated.

P.S.: I will have multiple different buttons on my store, and each one should open different popup since each item costs different amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put the contents of your paypal button (that you have mentioned in the question) in say "myfancybox.html"
 then in your file add:

```
<a data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="myfancybox.html">Pay</a>
```

Comment: Hm.. Can you or someone help me? I don't think I've done everything right..
Code I have in my head for fancybox:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });
 </script>`

And the extracted file I renamed to fancybox and placed next to my index.

Comment: check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ez73ummj/ Replace my iframe html content with that of yours